# Does Java Float.compare() Always Produce The Correct Result?

Tags: java, floating-point

This seems like a question that I could easily find an answer for but I couldn't see any entry on this. I know how the floating-point arithmetic works and in order to compare floating numbers I need to use an epsilon check. When I shared this with my team, one of my colleagues asked me this and I couldn't answer.

Does the compare method on Java always produce the correct result, i.e, the result an epsilon check for `f1` and `f2` would yield?

```
Float.compare(float f1, float f2);
```

**Note:** Especially consider this question for the equality case.

Comment: Can you inform us as to what an epsilon check is? I tried searching for it but I got nothing

Comment: It does not. It returns -1 for `f1 <  f2` and 1 for `f1 > f2`.

Comment: @ControlAltDel I think he mean https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.epsilon?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8

Comment: When you check if two floats are equal to each other, == operator may not give you the correct result because of the floating-point precision. Instead, you want to define an epsilon value that is really small (like 0.00001) and check if their absolute difference is smaller than epsilon.

Comment: How could a method not taking any epsilon value return the same thing as an epsilon check which, by definition, uses an epsilon, that could be 0.00001, or 0.1, or 2089? The javadoc tells what the method returns: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#compare-float-float-

Comment: A lot depends on what you mean by "correct". Each float number has a single value, and the value compare returns depends only on the ordering of those values. If, as is often the case, you are using float to approximate real numbers (WHY float, not double?), that ordering may or may not match the ordering of the values you would have got from real number arithmetic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `Float.compare` does not use any kind of epsilon checking.

Here's for example the OpenJDK 13 implementation of the method:

```
/**
 * Compares the two specified {@code float} values. The sign
 * of the integer value returned is the same as that of the
 * integer that would be returned by the call:
 * <pre>
 *    new Float(f1).compareTo(new Float(f2))
 * </pre>
 *
 * @param   f1        the first {@code float} to compare.
 * @param   f2        the second {@code float} to compare.
 * @return  the value {@code 0} if {@code f1} is
 *          numerically equal to {@code f2}; a value less than
 *          {@code 0} if {@code f1} is numerically less than
 *          {@code f2}; and a value greater than {@code 0}
 *          if {@code f1} is numerically greater than
 *          {@code f2}.
 * @since 1.4
 */
public static int compare(float f1, float f2) {
    if (f1 < f2)
        return -1;           // Neither val is NaN, thisVal is smaller
    if (f1 > f2)
        return 1;            // Neither val is NaN, thisVal is larger

    // Cannot use floatToRawIntBits because of possibility of NaNs.
    int thisBits    = Float.floatToIntBits(f1);
    int anotherBits = Float.floatToIntBits(f2);

    return (thisBits == anotherBits ?  0 : // Values are equal
            (thisBits < anotherBits ? -1 : // (-0.0, 0.0) or (!NaN, NaN)
             1));                          // (0.0, -0.0) or (NaN, !NaN)
}
```

[**Source**](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk13/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Float.java)

Comment: I checked this actually, but I wasn't sure how bit masks in it works. Anyway, thanks for making it clear.

Comment: As usual, Java source code is highly optimized for speed and not for readability. Furthermore, one should always follow the definitions in the javadoc (or the lack thereof) and not the implementation. Implementations may change, and may break your code if you rely on behavior that's *not* in Javadoc.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus Yes I agree completey. This example is to just show that the implementation does not use it, so it obviously cannot be part of the specification.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the Javadoc of `Float.compare()` they talk about "numerically equal". That means that values that *represent* the same theoretical number, but are differently encoded, are considered equal. Examples are `0.0 == -0.0` and subnormal numbers.

Epsilon checks (where you check if two numbers are within a *range* of one other, typically a very small number), is not a de-facto standard, and has a lot of practical issues (like which epsilon to choose when you don't know the magnutide of the numbers, or what to do when the two numbers have vastly different magnitudes). Because of that reason, Java only implements exact operations.

Answer (score 1):

No, [java.lang.Float.compare( double, double )](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Float.html#compare(float,float)) does not return 0 (equal) for values within a hidden epsilon value of each other.

However, you can easily do such a comparison by hand, or with one of a few common libraries.

**By hand,** you can write a function that returns zero if a fuzzy check for equality passes, else returns Float.compare(). The fuzzy check for equality can be something like `Math.abs( f1 - f2 ) < epsilon`.

Alternatively, in **[Apache Commons Math](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/)**, the [Precision](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/math3/util/Precision.htm) class provides compares() and equals() methods for floats and doubles that accept an epsilon value. And the class provides a value for epsilon in constant EPSILON.

Alternatively, in **[Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)**, the [DoubleMath](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/math/DoubleMath.html) class provides fuzzyCompare() and fuzzyEquals() methods that accept doubles and an epsilon value.

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like you need to check that two float values are equal within the given non-negative delta, correct?

You can use JUnit's [Assertions.assertEquals()](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertEquals(float,float,float)) method to achieve that:

```
assertEquals​(float f1, float f2, float delta)
```

Comment: Strange advise. That is a **test** library. How could you ever use that in **production** code?!

Comment: I think my question is very clear, I want to know if the given method does that.

Comment: @GhostCat says Reinstate Monica where do you see a production code?

Comment: Where do you see anything that says "test only" code?

Answer (score -2):

Commonly done with a test like:  `if (abs(a-b) < DELTA)` ... where DELTA is globally declared as some very-small numeric constant for consistency throughout the program.  Since the test is so very simple, I like to explicitly state it.

Comment: I think my question is very clear, I want to know if the given method does that.